# Failures - nodejs-lts (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs-lts\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Installing 64 bit version
Installing nodejs-lts...
WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\nodejs-lts_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.
ERROR: Running ["C:\WINDOWS\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs-lts\tools\node-v16.16.0-x64.msi" /qn /norestart /l*v "C:\Users\Nilay\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\nodejs-lts.16.16.0.MsiInstall.log" ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\nodejs-lts_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error..
The install of nodejs-lts was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs-lts\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - nodejs-lts (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nodejs-lts\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely have NodeJs latest installed already and are trying to install LTS which is older so it is exiting the MSI.

```
MSI (s) (2C:10) [23:25:50:400]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
Action ended 23:25:50: WixQueryOsWellKnownSID. Return value 1.
Action start 23:25:50: LaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (2C:10) [23:25:50:400]: Product: Node.js -- A later version of Node.js is already installed. Setup will now exit.

A later version of Node.js is already installed. Setup will now exit.
Action ended 23:25:50: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 23:25:50: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {47C07A3A-42EF-4213-A85D-8F5A59077C28}
Property(S): INSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files\nodejs\
Property(S): WixUIRMOption = UseRM
Property(S): WIXUI_INSTALLDIR = INSTALLDIR
```

Comment: bro, thanks so much!

Comment: You're very welcome, would you please mark this as your answer if it helped solve your issue.